# What does it mean for a mapping to be functorial in this given context?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, functors

What is meant in the following exercise by **functorial on A**?

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}\subset\operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ so that the category product $\prod_{i\in I} B_i$ with projections $\pi_j: \prod_{i\in I} B_i \to B_j$ for $j\in I$ exists. Prove that for any $A\in\operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ there exists a bijection of sets $$\phi: \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A, \prod_{i\in I} B_i)\to\prod_{i\in I}\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A, B_i)$$which is **functorial on $A$**.

A natural choice for me would be $\phi: f \mapsto \{\pi_i \circ f\}_{i\in I}$, which is bijective because of the universal property. So what is the property that I need to show now?

As this is a graded homework, please do not post solutions here. I only want to know what **functorial** means in this given context.

Thanks in advance to all contributors.

Comment: Authors who say "functorial" often mean "natural". That means that the family $(\phi_A)_A$ is a natural transformation between the obvious functors

Comment: Good to know! But for me it's not obvious: When you say a natural transformation, between which functors that go between which categories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by Max in the comments, the author means that the isomorphism $\phi$ is natural. If we have a morphism $\alpha : A' \to A$, then the following diagram must commute:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(A, \prod_{i\in I} B_i) @>{\phi}>> \prod_{i\in I} \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(A, B_i) \\
@VV{\overline \alpha}V @VV{\overline \alpha}V \\
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(A', \prod_{i\in I} B_i) @>{\phi}>> \prod_{i\in I} \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(A', B_i)
\end{CD}$$

$\overline \alpha$ is the precomposition with $\alpha$. Similarly, if we have a family of morphisms $\beta_i : B_i \to B'_i$ then the corresponding diagram induced by $\overline \beta_i$ must commute.

Of course, you can view the functor under consideration as a bifunctor and combine the diagrams above into one diagram and prove naturality in one step. The choice is up to you.

Comment: Just to note: the question is just about "functorial in $A$". So for the homework OP only has to consider the case with $\bar{\alpha}$ you mentioned, and not the $\beta_i$ case (although it might be a nice exercise to do that too).

Comment: Right, thanks for the note!

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, it is still not clear to me why that means that $\phi$ (or anything else) is a natural transformation of a functor $F: \mathcal{C}_1\to\mathcal{C}_2$ to a functor $G: \mathcal{C}_1\to\mathcal{C}_2$. What are $F,G,\mathcal{C}_1, \mathcal{C}_2$?

Comment: $F$ is a functor from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathrm{Set}$ mapping an object $A$ to $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(A, \prod_{i\in I} B_i)$. Likewise, $G$ maps $A$ to $\prod_{i\in I} \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(A, B_i)$.

Comment: That makes it clear to me now. Thanks a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Given $\mathcal{C}$, one can construct the category $[\mathcal{C}^\text{opp}, \textbf{Set}]$ of contravariant functors $\mathcal{C} \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$, with as morphisms the natural transformations. Now it turns out this category contains all products. This is so because if $\{F_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a collection of functors we can just use the fact that the product of sets is always defined and define for $X \in \mathcal{C}$
$$(\prod_i F_i) (X)= \prod_i F_i(X)$$,
and if $f : Y \rightarrow X$ in $\mathcal{C}$, just define
$$\prod_i F_i (f) ((x_i)_{i \in I})=(F_i(f)(x_i))_{i \in I}$$
where $x_i \in F_i(X)$. 
One can show we also have obvious projection maps $\pi_i \prod_i F_i \rightarrow \pi_i$ and that these together with the product
functor do indeed satisfy the universal property of the product. Now of course we already know a a lot of objects in $[\mathcal{C}^\text{opp}, \textbf{Set}]$  , namely the $\text{Hom}(-,X)$ for $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ an object. The formalisation of what you need to prove is: There is an isomorphism of contravariant functors
$$\text{Hom}(-, \prod_i B_i) \cong \prod_i \text{Hom}(-,B_i).$$

Comment: The OP explicitly asked for solutions not to be posted. They just wanted someone to clarify what functorial meant in the exercise.

Comment: This is not a solution

Comment: Thanks for that answer from a more abstract perspective!